# How to exclude mobx and mobx-react from the bundle using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, mobx, mobx-react

I'd like to exclude them from the bundle so that they can be cached by the browser. I tried this and a few variations without success in webpack.config.js. react and react-dom work fine.

```
externals: {
    "react": "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
    'mobx': "observable",
    'mobx-react': "observer"
},
```

I am bringing them in in my index.html

```
<script src="./node_modules/mobx/lib/mobx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/mobx-react/index.js"></script>
```

I am getting this error:

```
observable is not defined
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to highly confuse anyone else reading your code, or yourself in two months from now, use externals to import the lib instead of specific funcs :)

```
externals: {
    "react": "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
    'mobx': "mobx",
    'mobx-react': "mobxReact"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been confused by the externals syntax. It looks like it is libarary-name: global-var-name. And yet I don't find the global variable mobx nor mobxReact. Does any know?

Answer (score 0):

When you include `mobx` globally, you have to access `observable` from the global `mobx` variable:

```
class MyStore {
  @mobx.observable prop = [];
}
```

or:

```
var observable = mobx.observable;

class MyStore {
  @observable prop = [];
}
```